# Open PDF file in new browser in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to know, how to open a PDF file in new browser in shiny dashboard. In shiny i do it by using something like

```
 tabPanel(a("Packages Required",target="_blank",href="Packages.pdf")),
```

In shiny dashboard i would like to have it in `menuItem()`, i tried the below code, but didn't work.

```
menuItem("Reference Manual", tabName = "Reference",
         target="_blank", href="Reference.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about menuitem but you can do it using tags object. just make sure to create a www folder in the same place where server and ui file are saved and put Reference.pdf file there.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

tags$li(class = "dropdown",
       tags$a("Reference Manual",target="_blank",href="Reference.pdf",
       style="font-weight: bold;color:white;"))
```

Comment: This does not work. "Not Found" error appears on the new tab.